# How to designate a property as the Default Property for a VbScript class

Tags: vbscript, properties, object

Given that one can define a class in VB Script, is there any way to specify a default property for that class?

e.g. Given

```
Class MyClass
    Private myName 

    Public Property Get Name() 
        Name = myName
    End Property
end class
```

Is there anyway I can say that `Name` is the default property?

NB: To do this in VB6, one would add an attribute to the property, but **this doesn't work in VbScript**

```
Public Property Get Name() 
    Attribute Name.VB_MemberFlags = "200"
    Name = strName
End Property
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613k2d48.aspx) keyword:

```
Public Default Property Get Name
    Name = myName
End Property
```

---

**Edit:** Here're some tutorial and reference articles about using classes in VBScript, hope you'll find them useful:

- [Creating Classes with VBScript](http://www.activexperts.com/axscript/vbscriptclasses/)
- [Using Classes in VBScript](http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?action=viewarticle&articleid=9)
- [Creating Your Own Classes](http://www.herongyang.com/VBScript/Class-Create-Your-Own-Class.html)
- [Starting Object Oriented Programming in VBScript](http://www.suite101.com/content/starting-object-oriented-programming-in-vbscript-a134702)
- [VBScript in a Nutshell. Chapter 2: Program Structure](http://oreilly.com/catalog/vbscriptian/chapter/ch02.html) (section *Class Modules*)
- [Using Classes within VBScript](https://web.archive.org/web/20210505200200/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092399-1.shtml)

Comment: Helen, if I may ask, have you a reference for the classes end of VbScript? All I know are fragments picked up in odds and ends. Thanks.

Comment: @Binary: Added article links to the answer.